# Magento 2 After migration layer navigation not show on category page

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, magento2.3.1

After done magento 1.7.0.2 migration to magento 2.3.1 layer navigation not show on category page.

Answer (score 0):

> Catalog -> Manage Categories -> Your category -> Custom Design -> Page
>   Layout -> set "2 columns with left bar"